# How do you create NSMenuItem similar to Dropbox's menu dropdown?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Dropbox has a wonderful new dropdown view for their menubar app. I have failed to find similiar cocoa examples to duplicate this type of view. NSMenuItem seems to be for basic lists. Any pointers in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a `NSMenuItem`. It is a [`NSStatusItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that resides in the systemwide [`NSStatusBar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStatusBar). The distinction is important, because `NSStatusItem`s can call just about any method on any given object of your application when they're clicked.

I suspect that their `NSStatusItem` triggers an action that displays a borderless window.

You can find more information about status items in the [Status Bar Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/StatusBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000073i) document.

Comment: Hey Thanks; I was able to find an applicable example project [here](http://blog.shpakovski.com/2011/07/cocoa-popup-window-in-status-bar.html) if any one else is interested.